# tsung <if> statement or how to get current page in tsung?

Tags: erlang, load-testing, tsung

I have site with multiple redirects leading to login page. The number of redirects could vary and I solved it with :

```
<transaction name="get_login_page">
<request>
    <dyn_variable name="redirect" re="Location: ((http|https)://.*)\r"/>
    <http url='/' version='1.1' method='GET'>
    </http>
</request>
<repeat name="redirect_loop" max_repeat="5">
  <request subst="true">
    <dyn_variable name="redirect" re="Location: ((http|https)://.*)\r"/>
    <http url="%%_redirect%%" method="GET"></http>
  </request>
  <until var="redirect" eq=""/>
</repeat>
</transaction>
```

And from this point I have a problem, because on login page I have to submit data to current URL, but after last iteration variable "redirect" becomes empty. I've tried to create additional variable with  condition in cycle to save last non-empty value :

```
<transaction name="get_login_page">
<request>
    <dyn_variable name="redirect" re="Location: ((http|https)://.*)\r"/>
    <http url='/' version='1.1' method='GET'>
    </http>
</request>
<repeat name="redirect_loop" max_repeat="5">
  <request subst="true">
    <dyn_variable name="redirect" re="Location: ((http|https)://.*)\r"/>
    <if var="redirect" eq=''>
        <dyn_variable name="login_url" re="Location: ((http|https)://.*)\r"/>
    </if>
    <http url="%%_redirect%%" method="GET"></http>
  </request>
  <until var="redirect" eq=""/>
</repeat>
</transaction>
```

But now I've got an error on tsung run :

```
Starting Tsung
"Log directory is: /home/***/login_portal/logs/20141103-0945"
594- fatal: {failed_validation,element_unauthorize_in_choice}
Config Error, aborting ! {{badmatch,
                              {<<"<arrivalphase phase=\"1\" duration=\"5\" unit=\"second\">\n    <users maxnumber=\"1\" arrivalrate=\"1\" unit=\"second\"></users>\n</arrivalphase>\n">>,
                               {xmerl_sax_parser_state,undefined,
                                   #Fun<xmerl_sax_parser.1.53952608>,
                                   {file_descriptor,prim_file,
                                       {#Port<0.1047>,13}},
                                   #Fun<xmerl_sax_parser.default_continuation_cb.1>,
                                   utf8,1,
                                   [{"xml",
                                     "http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace"}],
                                   [],[],true,69656,no,normal,
                                   "/home/***/login_portal/.",
                                   "tsung_config_load.xml",false}}},
                          [{xmerl_sax_parser_utf8,handle_external_entity,2,
                               [{file,"xmerl_sax_parser_utf8.erl"},
                                {line,1692}]},
                           {xmerl_sax_parser_utf8,parse_external_entity,3,
                               [{file,"xmerl_sax_parser_utf8.erl"},
                                {line,1670}]},
                           {xmerl_sax_parser_utf8,parse_content,4,
                               [{file,"xmerl_sax_parser_utf8.erl"},
                                {line,1157}]},
                           {xmerl_sax_parser_utf8,parse_document,2,
                               [{file,"xmerl_sax_parser_utf8.erl"},
                                {line,179}]},
                           {xmerl_sax_parser_utf8,parse,2,
                               [{file,"xmerl_sax_parser_utf8.erl"},
                                {line,115}]},
                           {xmerl_sax_parser,file,2,
                               [{file,"xmerl_sax_parser.erl"},{line,77}]},
                           {ts_config,read,2,
                               [{file,"src/tsung_controller/ts_config.erl"},
                                {line,77}]},
                           {ts_config_server,handle_call,3,
                               [{file,
                                    "src/tsung_controller/ts_config_server.erl"},
                                {line,206}]}]}
```

Is there is a way to get last accessed URL or to get it from DOM model using built-in functions? Or how I should make  condition to let it work properly?